# Using column-count for responsive grid system

Tags: css, responsive, grid-layout

I would like to know if it's a good idea to use just `column-count` for making a simple grid system, instead of using `flex`, `grid`, or `float`.

It would look something like this:

```
.2col { column-count: 2}
.3col { column-count: 3}
.4col { column-count: 4}

 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .2col { column-count: 1}
    .3col { column-count: 1}
    .4col { column-count: 1}
}
```

Is anybody using this?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use it. It is not flexible enough (yet) for common scenarios.

I once had the same idea, started to use it, but very quickly reached the point where I could not fix some alignments .